# Facebook C# authentication mixed with forms

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Anyone who can provide sample, or a up to date guide on how to create a .net 4.0 MVC page that uses form authentication and facebook login at the same time.

I would like to provide the users the option to use there facebook login and if they dont have an account they can create an account on our page and use this login. (dont want to force them to create a facebook account).

I have created a MVC 3 project, added Facebook, Facebook.web, Facebook.Web.Mvc libs and do not know how to proceed. Adding login button and mixing it up with the standard forms login in asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `forms authentication` you can simple login with Facebook and use the user id upon logged in to set you the forms session.

The same way you log in a user using a `username` and `password` textbox, you simple log in the user as you already know what `user_id` wants to continue in your site.

when using the Facebook C# SDK, you can simple set you your `APP_ID` and `APP_SECRET` in the shared view and add a

```
<fb:login-button perms="email" size="medium">
        Login using your Facebook Account</fb:login-button>
```

Your Action will now be able o access the user basic info plus the `email`, use that information to store the `Facebook ID` as well and the next time the user connects, just use

```
FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated()
```

and get the information from FB like

```
var client = new FacebookWebClient();
dynamic me = client.Get("me");

ViewBag.Name = me.name;
ViewBag.Id = me.id;
ViewBag.Email = me.email;
```

with all this info, just set the sessions you are using with your forms authentication provider.

Comment: I do not find any login-button in the facebook namespace?

Comment: `fb:login-button` is FBML, not C#! If you having difficulties to know the difference, you should start reading more about Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Comment: fb:login-button dont state its FBML anyway, it could have been a usercontrol. I got the the login button and such working now, but still in need more information on the topic of integrading the facebook authentication with the forms. Using the role system and not having to do FacebbokWebContex.Current.IsAuthenticated() || mebership.IsAuthenticated() ect.

Comment: `<fb:>` states it's Facebook Markup Language! As I keep saying, and probably you didn't read, you simply need to set the sessions on Authentication and then you can use `Membership.IsAuthenticated()`.

Comment: <fb:> could have been some user control in an asp.net page. (Not all uses razor). But the part about settings the sessions are still unclear to me. I seek more detailed guideness.

Comment: what more detailed? just see where you do the login and by pass it! you give no code at all, we can't just tell you what to do without seeing what you tried before!